# disable android back while showModalBottomSheet opened

Tags: flutter

My widget inside showModalBottomSheet is a textfield , user must fill up correct value in order to proceed next function, I know there is a ready param called `isDismissible` , however it only disable from taping backdrop, it doesn't diable android back.

```
return showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can wrap your widget with `WillPopScope`

For example:

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async => false,
)
```